# math.round not working with doubles

Tags: c#

my doubles get not rounded as expected. Simple example:

```
 int b = 23;
 double DurchflussAktBit = 99.5;
 double bDurchfluss = 0;

 bDurchfluss = DurchflussAktBit * Convert.ToDouble(b) / (double)60;
 Math.Round(bDurchfluss, 2);
```

I get the value `38.141666666666666` for `bDurchfluss` even after the rounding, I expect the value `38.14`. Also tried      `Math.Round((decimal)bDurchfluss, 2);` but gives me the same value.

Where is the error in my code?

Comment: Functions return results, you don't do anything with your result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the rounded number - it does *not* update the number you passed it.

You need to take the return value and assign it to your variable:

```
 bDurchfluss = DurchflussAktBit * Convert.ToDouble(b) / (double)60;
 bDurchfluss = Math.Round(bDurchfluss, 2);
```

Comment: outch, that hurts... sry for the question and thanks for the answer!

Comment: @katz No worries, mate.